# IOTypes error OSTypes not found

Tags: theos

I am using Theos and when I use Make Package, I get the error:

```
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOKit/IOKitLib.h:49:
/Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOKit/IOTypes.h:56:10: fatal error: 
      'libkern/OSTypes.h' file not found
#include <libkern/OSTypes.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.fe4c9a81.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [Welcomer.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I checked and the file OSTypes.h does exist in the libkern folder. I am using rpetrich's iPhone headers from his github.

Terminal:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:welcomer jordan$ make package
/Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while       building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak Welcomer...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from <built-in>:184:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/Prefix.pch:4:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITableView.h:11:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/UIKit/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISwipeGestureRecognizer.h:9:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.h:6:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/UIKit/UIKit-Structs.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:30:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/QuartzCore/CAValueFunction.h:9:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-Structs.h:11:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurface.h:20:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h:12:
In file included from /Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOKit/IOKitLib.h:49:
/Users/jordan/welcomer/theos/include/IOKit/IOTypes.h:56:10: fatal error: 
      'libkern/OSTypes.h' file not found
#include <libkern/OSTypes.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.fe4c9a81.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [Welcomer.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:welcomer jordan$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSTypes.h is missing from the iPhoneOS.sdk, I copied it from the iPhoneSimulator.sdk as follows:

```
sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSTypes.h /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libkern
```

Comment: My current xcode install does not have this. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr only has 'lib' in it.